# Optional DateTime in SOAP request turns into DateTime in service reference

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

My application needs to query third party SOAP service.
When using SOAP UI, it generates this sample request for one of the methods:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:wsedi">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:listMBAllExXML>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <name>?</name>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <password>?</password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <receiveBinary>?</receiveBinary>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <lastDate>?</lastDate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <uuid>?</uuid>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <direction>?</direction>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <status>?</status>
      </urn:listMBAllExXML>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`lastDate` is commented as optional, and API documentation from service developers confirms this.

But when I'm using "Add service reference..." menu in Solution Explorer, I'm getting this generated wrapper:

```
listMBAllExModel listMBAllExXML(string name, string password, bool receiveBinary, System.DateTime lastDate, string uuid, string direction)
{
    // some code...
}
```

As you can see, `lastDate` is of type `DateTime`, not `DateTime?`. Hence, I can't omit it.

Is this a problem with the WSDL?
Are there any workarounds (to write service wrapper by hand isn't a good option)?

UPDATE.

Here's part of XSD, contained in service reference folder:

```
  <xs:complexType name="listMBAllExXML">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="receiveBinary" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastDate" type="xs:dateTime" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="uuid" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="direction" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

`lastDate` hasn't `nillable="true"`.

Comment: is that field `nillable="true"` in the wsdl? I checked an API I'm using and I get a nullable DateTime generated.

Comment: @Crowcoder: unfortunately, no. I've updated the question.

Comment: Unfortunately it will be somewhat messy for you to handle. With all the promise of SOAP interoperability, I've never had an integration with disparate systems go smoothly.